# How to fetch date from datetime?

Tags: python, date, xls, python-datetime

I have a datetime information in following format in the .XLS file, e.g.
15-MAR-21 01.32.50.395000 PM

[image]

I need to convert this timestamp to date object (and update it in a new column). How to fetch date from this datetime object?

**Update: Here is my solution**

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_str = '15-MAR-21 01.32.50.395000 PM'

datetime_object = datetime.strptime(datetime_str, '%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%S.%f %p')

print(type(datetime_object))
print(datetime_object)  # printed in default format

print(datetime_object.date())
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Read the datetime.datetime.strptime docs which tell you how to do this. If you have problems, post how you tried to use it here.

Comment: @576i Thank-you for your inputs, I just posted a solution can you please have a look

Comment: What you have is the best solution.

Comment: There is an error in the string to parse `datetime_str`: you should change `%H` with `%I`, given that you are using `AM` and `PM`. However, this should not affect the result of `date()`.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply import datetime library and then use datetime.datetime.date() method for this

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your file is called `date_file.xlsx` and that the column with the dates is named `DATE`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.read_excel(
    'date_file.xlsx',
    converters={
        'DATE': lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p').date()
    },
    engine='openpyxl',
)
```

The column `DATE` of `df` will contain all the converted dates. if you prefer a `datetime.datetime` object, remove `.date()` from the parsing function.

In your example, `15-MAR-21 01.32.50.395000 PM` will be converted to `2021-03-15`, and, if you remove `.date()`, to `2021-03-15 13:32:50.395`.

Comment: the OP seems to need a new column; your code snippet converts upon import (and doesn't update the xls file)